# Replace value based on condition within groups in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is something like

**df**

```
group cat_col
g1    r
g1    nr
g1    r
g1    nr
g2    nr
g2    nr
```

I need to replace "nr" for "r" whenever the group has at least 1 "r".
In this case, I need it to return:

**df_new**

```
group cat_col
g1    r
g1    r
g1    r
g1    r
g2    nr
g2    nr
```

I know this question is elementary, but I'm stuck for hours and I didn't figure out how to solve it. Does someone know?

Comment: I assume you're using Pandas, so I added the [tag:pandas] tag for you. If that's incorrect, you can [edit] to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby.transform`:

```
df.cat_col.groupby(df.group).transform(lambda g: 'r' if g.eq('r').any() else g)

0     r
1     r
2     r
3     r
4    nr
5    nr
Name: cat_col, dtype: object
```

If only need to replace `nr` with `r`:

```
df.cat_col = df.cat_col.groupby(df.group).transform(
  lambda g: g.replace('nr', 'r') if g.eq('r').any() else g
)
```

Comment: Nice one, however this will not work if the requirement is "to change only nr to r" and there are other values except from r and nr. OP must clarify this

Answer (score 1):

We can also use [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to see if there are `any` values in each group that [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) `r` and use this Boolean index to then replace those values with `r`:

```
m = df['cat_col'].eq('r').groupby(df['group']).transform('any')
df.loc[m, 'cat_col'] = 'r'
```

Or conditionally [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) `nr` with `r` using the same boolean index (in case there are multiple replace values):

```
m = df['cat_col'].eq('r').groupby(df['group']).transform('any')
df.loc[m, 'cat_col'] = df.loc[m, 'cat_col'].replace({'nr': 'r'})
```

`df`:

```
  group cat_col
0    g1       r
1    g1       r
2    g1       r
3    g1       r
4    g2      nr
5    g2      nr
```

---

Boolean index steps in a DataFrame:

```
steps_df = pd.DataFrame({
    # Find where cat_col is r
    'step 1': df['cat_col'].eq('r'),
    # Find groups which have an r value
    'step 2': df['cat_col'].eq('r').groupby(df['group']).transform('any')
})
```

```
   step 1  step 2
0    True    True
1   False    True
2    True    True
3   False    True
4   False   False
5   False   False
```

---

Setup (DataFrame and imports):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ['g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g2', 'g2'],
    'cat_col': ['r', 'nr', 'r', 'nr', 'nr', 'nr']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
l=df[df['cat_col']=='r']['group'].to_list()

df.loc[df['group'].isin(l), 'cat_col'] = df.loc[df['group'].isin(gr), 'cat_col'].replace('nr', 'r')
```

Output:

```
>>> print(df)
  group cat_col
0    g1       r
1    g1       r
2    g1       r
3    g1       r
4    g2      nr
5    g2      nr
```

Answer (score 0):

This has a few more steps but I think is quite clear to follow:

```
groups_that_pass_the_condition = []
groups = df.group.unique()

for group in groups:
    cat_col_by_group = df.loc[df.group == group]['cat_col']
    value_counts = cat_col_by_group.value_counts()
    if 'r' in value_counts.index:
        if value_counts.r >= 1:
            groups_that_pass_the_condition.append(group)

for group_that_passed in groups_that_pass_the_condition:
    df.loc[df.group == group_that_passed] = df.loc[df.group == group_that_passed].replace('nr', 'r')

print(df)
```

OUT:

```
  group cat_col
0    g1       r
1    g1       r
2    g1       r
3    g1       r
4    g2      nr
5    g2      nr
```